# Is there a fast database that does approx results if allowed - accurate results when asked for

Tags: database, lsf

I create job arrays of thousands of simulations that get executed on a network connected cluster of servers which all have local disk as well being connected to NFS disc drives.

Is there a database that can be distributed amongst the servers that operates in the following way:

1. When I submit my job array each individual job running on an individual server to send results to the distributed DB.
2. Whilst the job array is still running the user can request partial summaries from the DB - the DB having the option to not wait for all the *latest* results from all its distributed nodes, but to "improvise" in some way
3. The user can request a full summary after the job array is finished which causes the DB to ensure that it returns an accurate summary of all data from all its nodes and further, that all nodes are not still receiving data from jobs (quiescent for a stated time).

In other words, I want a fast DB and an accurate DB when I tell it, receiving lots of data from thousands of jobs in an LSF job array. I need to monitor the progress of the LSF job array's results but am willing to forego some accuracy when monitoring to increase speed, but need an accurate result when all is done.

The data being stored for each job is small job ID, small PASS/FAIL, large how job fails. The how is likely to be only spot-checked for a very few jobs until the end of all jobs in the job-array when triage scripts will need access to all DB data for the job array at speed.